# Send Multiple Commands to External Program

Tags: powershell, scripting, redis

We are trying to write a PowerShell script that invokes an external application -- a Redis client (`redis-cli.exe`) -- and then sends multiple commands to that .exe. We have no issue sending individual commands like the below:

```
& redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 SMEMBERS someKey
```

The problem is that this will start a Redis client, issue a single command, close the client, and then return control to PowerShell. We need to issue multiple commands in a transaction. For example, here are the commands that we want to send to the client:

```
MULTI
DEL someKey
DEL someSet
EXEC
```

The Redis client does support sending a LUA script string as a command, but this unfortunately doesn't support the MULTI/EXEC transactional commands. In other words, we need to be able to issue multiple commands like I listed above.

Comment: I don't know about PowerShell, but on my (Linux) box redis-cli takes multiple commands on standard input: `echo -e "MULTI\nEXEC" | redis-cli` shows `OK`.

Comment: In PowerShell piping an array of strings should do the same: `'MULTI', 'DEL someKey', ... | redis-cli ...`, provided the Windows version read from STDIN as well.

Comment: Awesome, it appears to work! :) If you want to post this as an answer I'll upvote and accept. E.g. : echo "MULTI","EXEC" | & redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `redis-cli` appears to read input from STDIN you could feed it an array with the command strings like this:

```
'MULTI', 'EXEC' | & redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379
```

Using `echo` (alias for `Write-Output`) is not required for feeding the array into the pipeline.

You could also store the command array in a variable first:

```
$cmds = 'MULTI', 'EXEC'
$cmds | & redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379
```